# Tyring to use importXML to get RSS data, but my URL points to invalid XML

Tags: xml-parsing, rss, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my function in the google spreadsheet:

```
=ImportXML("http://forums.redflagdeals.com/external.php?type=RSS2&forumids=9"; "//a/@href")
```

I get this error:

```
"error: The data could not be parsed. Please make sure that the URL points to valid XML or HTML."
```

I am guessing that what the URL produces isn't a typical XML document, but my browser and various RSS readers can deal with it fine.

Is there some way that I can still use this URL to get the RSS data using google spreadsheets or scripts in an automated way? I don't want to have to manually save the XML doc each time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a very old thread (2009) [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Q4puETL12g4) that claims that the `ImportXML()` function has trouble with RSS feeds created using a two-stage process.

There is another spreadsheet function that works with the URL you've provided.

```
=ImportFeed("http://forums.redflagdeals.com/external.php?type=RSS2&forumids=9")
```

An excerpt from the documation [here](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=155181):

> **ImportFeed**
>
> The ImportFeed function retrieves information from a data
>   feed. For example, it can import an RSS or ATOM feed, just as you can
>   in Google Reader.
>
> Here's how to format your ImportFeed function:
>
> ```
> =ImportFeed(URL; [feedQuery | itemQuery]; [headers]; [numItems]).
> ```